# bug when asking for my responses

Tags: bug, profile-page

In my profile on Main, I have a choice of many items, such as "all actions" or "responses." For a few days, when I click on "responses" it times out. However, it works with "all actions."

I should note that I updated Firefox within the last few days.

Comment: evidently this is the same question. They mention a work-around but no genuine fix.